# Button won't fit in to space left by two text area elements

Tags: css, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height : 100%">
    <body style="height : 100%; margin: 0;">
        <span style="height : 100%; margin: 0;">
            <textarea id="chatbox" readonly="true" style="width : 100%; height : 90%; display : block; margin : 0; border : 0; resize : none;"></textarea>

            <textarea id="input" style="width : 95%; height : 10%; border : 1%; display : block; resize : none;"></textarea>
            <button id="submit" style="width : 5%; height : 10%;">Submit</button>
        </span>
    </body>
</html>
```

The button insists on staying below the second text area. How can I make it append to the end of the second text area instead?

Comment: It works fine for me, with which browser do you have this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of issues you need to correct.

1. It is generally perceived as best practice to move your styles from inline to a stylesheet
2. Your button and textarea are inline elements with a combined width of 100%- however this doesnt take into account their padding, margin or border, all of which adds additional width- as such you need to set `box-sizing:border-box` for them to take this into account
3. Your button and textarea are inline items, in your HTML they are on seperate lines- this is rendered as a space character which adds more 'width' to the line, exceeding the 100% - to correct this set them to `display:block` then use `float:left` (the alternative would be to place them on the same line in your HTML)

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/78dmK/)

Change your HTML to:

```
<span>
    <textarea id="chatbox" readonly="true"></textarea>
    <textarea id="input" ></textarea>
    <button id="submit" >Submit</button>
</span>
```

And your CSS:

```
span {
    height : 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
textarea, button {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
textarea:first-of-type {
    width : 100%;
    height : 90%;
    display : block;
    margin : 0;
    border : 0;
    resize : none;
}
textarea:last-of-type {
    width : 95%;
    height : 10%;
    border : 1%;
    resize : none;
}
button {
    width : 5%;
    height : 10%;
}
```

Comment: `width` and `display` (`block` or `inline-block`) on span?

Answer (score 0):

Looks as if you didn't account for the 1% border on your input textarea?

Answer (score 0):

you must write **display: inline-block** for secont textarea and button. also you have to **decrease textarea width percentage**.

the working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Da2F4/)

```
    <textarea id="input" style="width : 93%; height : 10%; border : 1%; display : inline-block; resize : none; vertical-align: bottom;"></textarea>
    <button id="submit" style="width : 5%; height : 10%; display:inline-block;">Submit</button>
```